# Spinnaker - Reference ConfigMap versioned value inside manifest

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I'm deploying a single yaml file containing two manifests using the Spinnaker Kubernetes Provider V2 (Manifest deployer). Inside the Deployment I have a custom annotation that references the ConfigMap:

```
# ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1 
kind: ConfigMap 
metadata: 
  name: my-config-map
data: 
  foo: bar
---
# Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        my-config-map-reference: my-config-map
  [...]
```

Upon deployment, Spinnaker applies versioning to the ConfigMap, which is then deployed as `my-config-map-v000`.

I'd like to be able to retrieve the full name inside my custom annotation, but since Spinnaker replaces automatically the configMap references with the appropriate versioned values only in specific entrypoints ( https://github.com/spinnaker/clouddriver/blob/master/clouddriver-kubernetes/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/clouddriver/kubernetes/v2/artifact/ArtifactReplacerFactory.java ) in this case this does not work.

According to Spinnaker documentation ( https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/artifacts/in-kubernetes-v2/#why-not-pipeline-expressions ) I may be able to write a Pipeline Expression to retrieve the full name, but I wasn't able to do so.

How can I set the full ConfigMap name inside the annotation?

Comment: Were you able to find a SpEL for this?

Answer (score 0):

Spinnaker can inject artifacts from the currently executing pipeline into your manifests as they are deployed

Refer to this guide for the instructions on how to [Binding artifacts in manifests](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/artifacts/in-kubernetes-v2/#binding-artifacts-in-manifests)

However, as mentioned [here](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/providers/kubernetes/#reserved-annotations), there's **NO** resource mapping for annotation, so it should be user-supplied only as a [parameter for your manifest](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/kubernetes-v2/parameterize-manifests/#parameterize-kubernetes-manifests).

In the future, certain relationships between resources will be recorded and annotated by Spinnaker